# x2go printer sharing trouble

Tags: linux, debian, printing, x2go

I have a got  x2go server installed on Debian 8 by official manual:

On server-side:

```
sudo aptitude install x2goserver x2goserver-printing cups cups-x2go
```

I login on server as user with x2goclient. I install Virtual X2Go Printer.

Messages

```
/usr/bin/x2gomountdirs[19925]: successfully mounted user@127.0.0.1:30012/home/user/.x2go/S-dpk_2_oper-53-1453706771_stDXFCE_dp24/spool to /tmp/.x2go-dpk_2_oper/spool/C-dpk_2_oper-53-1453706771_stDXFCE_dp24
```

After print:

```
 Print job received from cups -> 1 dpk_2_oper Безымянный1 1 PageSize=A4 job-uuid=urn:uuid:90063044-2265-33af-7b7c-104dff51a713 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1453704245 time-at-processing=1453704245 document-name-supplied=zL0lzH
```

But on client side nothing happens. What could I forget?

X2go create root owned pdf with job name in '/' with 600 permission.